# Not able to select first element using css selector

Tags: behat

I have a requirement where HTML elements have following structure.

```
<div class="user">
<a href="#">Name</a>
<a href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
```

I want to click on first element using css selector.

I am using Behat 3 for automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in multiple ways, one of them is to use the existing step:

```
I follow "Name"
```

Another way is to find the element and use the `click()` on it, or to create a custom step that clicks on the element by selector, for example using css selector `I click ".user a"`